# Why won't the control panel window appear?

Tags: windows-7, control-panel

Has anybody ever struck this before?

I open control panel in Windows 7 and the icon appears in my tray as if it's open, but no window appears... as if the control panel is minimized but can't be restored or maximized.

Any ideas or solutions greatly appreciated.

All else appears fine.

Comment: I presume you mean task bar and not tray.

Comment: Do you have a second monitor/projector which is turned off?

Comment: What happens if you right-click it and try to "move" it back onto the screen?  Alternatively, click the icon so the Window is in-focus, and use WinKey+L or WinKey+R to try and snap the window to your screen.